# How to reduce size of .tiff file

Tags: file, size, tiff, reduce

I am unaware of how to reduce the size of .tif/.tiff extension file. Though I can reduce the size by changing to jpg file but I need it in **.tif /.tiff.** Kindly help.

Comment: The tiff format supports compression, you should look into that.

Comment: Note that StackOverflow is for questions related to programming and software development. If you just want to reduce the size of an image using standard tools, you should ask at a different SE site, like SuperUser or similar. See the [Help Center on topic section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

Opening it in Photoshop and exporting as a .tiff should yield a compression option. I'm not sure if supported, but you could also try GIMP.

"Generally when you save a TIFF in Photoshop, you'll see a dialog that is titled "TIFF Options". The first option is for Image Compression. You can choose the type of compression you want to use: None, LZW, ZIP, or JPEG."
- http://www.reuniontalk.com/showthread.php?t=8733